# Deactivate user from CouchDB database

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have created a list of users in _Users database in couchDB, now I want to deactivate user, meaning the user cannot be logged into the the CouchDB. I do not want to delete the user from _Users database list, instead the user should not able to login. I am new to CouchDB can any one provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change their password to a random value?